# How to add Custom Units in Petrel with Ocean?

Tags: ocean, petrel

I want to add custom units in Petrel's custom unit system through Ocean.
As suggested in the developers guide, I used the following code:

```
IUnitService unitService = Slb.Ocean.Core.CoreSystem.GetService(); 
IUnitCatalog catalog = unitService.GetCatalog(null); 
System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary map = 
       new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(); 
map["Pressure"] = "MyUnit"; 
catalog.CreateCustomUnitSystem("My UnitSystem", 
                               "UnitSystem for my additional units.", 
                                map, 
                                "MyUnitSystem");
```

I put that code in the Initialize and Integrate methods. 
In both cases, Ocean throws a SEHException.

Any idea of what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The custom unit system that you create must be based on an existing unit system. 

The existing unit system name is used as the reference system in the method CreateCustomUnitSystem. 

Existing unit systems include the Canonical and Display unit systems that are available from IUnitServiceSettings. 

Here is an example code that creates a custom unit system:

```
IUnitService unitService = CoreSystem.GetService( );
IUnitCatalog catalog = unitService.GetCatalog( null );
IUnitServiceSettings uss = CoreSystem.GetService( );
IUnitSystem refSystem = uss.InvariantSystem;
IDictionary map = new Dictionary( );
map["Pressure"] = "MyUnit";
ICustomUnitSystem myUnitSystem = catalog.CreateCustomUnitSystem( "My UnitSystem", "Unit System for my additional units.", map, refSystem.Name );
```

The custom unit system will not change any of the Petrel templates, nor will it be added to the Template tab in the Petrel Explorer window